# How to set an Image fit to width of ScrollViewer

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've Image placed inside a ScrollViewer.

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="imageScroller" Grid.Column="2" Margin="5" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
    <Image x:Name="imageViewer" Cursor="Hand" RenderTransformOrigin="0,0" Margin="0">
        <Image.LayoutTransform>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding Path=Zoom, Converter={StaticResource debugConverter}}" ScaleY="{Binding Path=Zoom, Converter={StaticResource debugConverter}}"/>
        </Image.LayoutTransform>
    </Image>
</ScrollViewer>
```

How do I zoom image like "fit-to-width" in document viewers to the size and height of ScrollViewer?

Answer (score 3):

I'm doing this by setting the scale for the ScaleTransform in a event handler for the ScrollViewer Load event.  Basically I divide the ActualWidth of the ScrollViewer by the width of the source of the image.  I also have a handler for the ScrollViewer SizeChanged event that will recalulate the scale so that the image will shrink and grow if you resize your window.  Here's some basic code.

Note: This does not take the vertical scrollbar into account, in fact a search on how to handle that is how I ended up here.  I'll update when I find an answer for that.

```
private void imageScroller_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FitToWidth();
}

private void imageScroller_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if(imageScroller.IsLoaded)
        FitToWidth();
}

private void FitToWidth()
{
    scaler.ScaleX = scaler.ScaleY = imageScroller.ActualWidth / imageViewer.Source.Width;
}
```

Comment: In my case I needed the image to scroll horizontally but stretch vertically, so setting the ScaleY in this way and disabling the vertical scrollbar did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

`ScrollViewer` is not right choice for this. It gives all available space for its child unless you disable scrolling. To stretch images, we usually use `Stretch="Fill"` property, but, again, it will not work with ScrollViewer.

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="imageScroller" Margin="5" 
              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <Image x:Name="imageViewer" Cursor="Hand" RenderTransformOrigin="0,0" Margin="0" 
           Stretch="Fill"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

This approach will work for stretching image, but it disables scrolling.

Comment: this will focused on image to the left side, unable to zoom the image from right side

Comment: Very incorrect answer. `ScrollViewer` is the best option.